# Changing position of text in objects from common library & copying layer structure to another file

Tags: layers, adobe-fireworks, text

this is a double question (to avoid wasting space :P)

**1**: How can I precisely move the text of an element from the common library? I'm currently using a mac text field and after resizing it the text is offset. Double clicking on it takes me to its editing page, but moving the text there by just one pixel moves it too much when I return to the wider version, so I'm not able to change it precisely:

This is how it looks inside the page:
[image: the text element inside the page]

And here's how it looks when I double click on it to edit its elements:
[image: The element when edited singularly]

After I nudge it to the left and return to the page, it's displayed like this:
[image: The element after being nudged]

This means the control is not precise enough. How can I move the text more precisely?

**2**: I need to restructure a design by joining two different files (which represent two different states of the same page) together. I tried doing this by dragging all the content of one file, selected with Ctrl-A, to the other file but layer structure (groups, etc.) is not preserved.
I'd like to know a way to make it preserve the layer structure entirely and make it copy hidden layers too. Is that possible?

Comment: You really should make this into two separate questions as they deal with completely different aspects of Fireworks. Multi-part questions are acceptable, but only when the questions are directly relevant to each other.

Answer (score 1):

If the offset text for symbol is oneshot-situation, use the Break Apart -command (via right-click or Modify-menu "Symbol/Break Apart" to convert symbol back to vectors.